# How to enable design options for a custom OptinSkin skin

Tags: html, css, wordpress, skin

Does anyone here have experience with OptinSkin for WordPress.

Original OptinSkins have Design Options you can change from the admin. (see image: http://postimg.org/image/47ptmvzt9/ )

**Original Skin Code Excerpt**

```
<div class="ois_title_16" style="font-family: '%title-font%', Arial !important; color: %title-color%   !important;font-size:%title-size%;padding: %title-pos-top% 0 %beneath-title% %title-pos-left%;">
```

I created my own design using CSS, however, the design options are not being shown in the admin page. I figured out that the original skins use slightly different CSS rules to enable or "call" the specific field on the admin page.

When I change my CSS declaration values to match the ones from the original code - nothing happens.

Does anyone know how I can enable the Design Options for custom skins?

Comment: May be http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: you have to write some code for the Admin panel to display your own custom options for design.